# When a Role is added to user, send message in a text channel

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I would like when I add a role to a user, the bot sends a message to a text channel.  How would I do this please?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take a minute and [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and consider updating your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the [**guildMemberUpdate**](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberUpdate) event.

Here is an example of how you could do this:

```
 const Discord = require('discord.js');
    exports.run = async (client, oldMember, newMember) => {
        const messagechannel = msg.guild.channels.find('name', 'YOUR NAME OF YOUR CHANNEL');
        if (oldMember.roles.size < newMember.roles.size) {
            const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                .setColor('#FE2E2E')
                .setTimestamp()
                .setAuthor('Role added!')
                .addField(`Member:`, `${oldMember.user.tag} (${oldMember.id})`);
            for (const role of newMember.roles.map(x => x.id)) {
                if (!oldMember.roles.has(role)) {
                    embed.addField(`Role:`, `${oldMember.guild.roles.get(role).name}`);
                }
            }
            messagechannel.send({
                embed
            });
        }
    }
```